# How do I write a mysql query that will read data from one table and write to another?

Tags: mysql, sql

If this is possible, please provide a sample query or two so I can see how it would work.  Both tables will be in the same database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
insert into <target-table>
( <column-list> )
select <columns>
  from <source-table>
```

Answer (score 4):

`INSERT...SELECT` is the answer; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO names
SELECT last_name, first_name
FROM people
```